# Symfony dynamically add or remove subforms

Tags: javascript, symfony

I have got a form class MyClassType with my builder

```
$builder->add('options', ChoiceType::class, [
'choices' => [
    'option1',
    'option2',
    'option3',
    'option4'
]])
// some other stuff
->add('subform1', Subform1Type::class)
->add('subform2', Subform2Type::class)
->add('subform3', Subform3Type::class);
```

and a view with

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_label(form.options) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.options) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.options) }}

    {{ form_label(form.subform1) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.subform1) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.subform1) }}

    {{ form_label(form.subform2) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.subform2) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.subform2) }}

    {{ form_label(form.subform3) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.subform3) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.subform3) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

and my Controller Class function

```
$myClass = new MyClass();
$form = $this->createForm(MyClassType::class, $myClass);
$form->handleRequest($request);

return $this->render('default/myClassView.html.twig',[
    'form' => $form->createView()
]);
```

what i want to do is to have subforms depending on the option i choose. For example option1 gives me subform1 but also something like option4 gives me subform2 and subform3.

I want to do this because i have ManyToOne relations of the subform data to MyClass but MyClass sometimes has data only from subform1 etc.

I'm not really sure how to do this. Is this what EventListeners are for?
What I mean is something like: in MyClassType

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA // or something similiar
    function (FormEvent $event) {
        // do some magic here
    }
);
```

or is it possible to do some JavaScript magic? I don't really want just to hide my subform because it would be still there

Comment: If you need "real time" (e.g.: without posting the form before having back some results) you need to implement your own logic through an API that feeds an ajax call from the client

Comment: Do you mean something like `<script>function changeForm() { /*do some stuff*/ } </script>`, if so I'm not sure what the stuff should be. Maybe it is possible to initially have no subform at all and to chose an option so that subform are generated/added to the form and the view gets rerendered. Would be nice to have this in "real time" but a button (submit?) would be ok

Comment: i believe that yes, 'addEventListener' is the way to go (or atleast the way i would go first)

Comment: so I would do something like `$data = $event->getData(); $form = $event->getForm(); $form->add('subform1', Subform1Type::class);` in my EventListener function? But how do I add this in my twig template? And do I do a switch on `$data->get('options')` or something similiar? I'm not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it myself. So I'm gonna give you what I did.
Add a EventListener to MyClassType as seen above

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA 
    function (FormEvent $event) {
        $entity = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        if($entity->getSubform1() !== null){
            $form->add('subform1', Subform1Type::class);
        }
    }
);
```

As an alternative you could add a EventSubscriber

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddFormFieldsSubscriber());
```

and write a new Class

```
class AddUrkundenFieldsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
            $entity = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            if($entity->getSubform1() !== null){
                $form->add('subform1', Subform1Type::class);
            }
    }
}
```

in my Controller Class I use $_SESSION to store my myClass so something like

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $this->get('session');
    if(!$session->get('myClass')){
        $myClass = new MyClass();
    } else {
        $myClass = $session->get('myClass')
    }

    // create and handle form etc

    if($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $myClass = $form->getData();
        if($myClass->getSubform1() === null) {
            $myClass->setSubform1(new Subform1());
            $session->set('myClass', $myClass);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('thisPage');
        } else { /* redirect to another page */ }

    retrun /* create form view */;
    }}
```

Also I had to implement the following function in my Subform1 Class

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Subform1',
    ]);
}
```

in the Twig File you can then do something like

```
{% if form.subform1 is defined %}
{{ form_widget(form.subform1) }}
{% endif %}
```